# Retrieve all Outlinks in Doors DXL

Tags: ibm-doors

I used dxl code to retrieve all outlinks and it works ok .

But it seems it retrieve just some links and neglect others , and i don't know why !

here is code snippet

```
Object o
string label
Module m = read(planSpecReportPath_inDoors)
Link outLink
for o in m do
{
    for outLink in o -> "*" do
    {   
        parentModName = target(outLink)
        iTarget= targetAbsNo(outLink)
```

can any one tell me what is general solution to get all outlinks ? and what is i am missing ?

thanks

Comment: I think i knew what is going on , it gets all outlinks to current modules , not Baselines ! , can any one help me with that ?

Answer (score 3):

first of all, for clarity's sake I though I should mention that your comment says your script gets all outlinks to current modules, but the script you posted will only retrieve outlinks from the module at path planSpecReportPath_inDoors. You can change the script to work for the current module by modifying your code to the following:

```
Module m = current Module
```

Secondly, if I understand your question and comment correctly, you want to cycle through each outlink in a module, including the outlinks from previous baselines right? this can be done with a fairly simple script:

```
Module baselineM = null
Module m = read(planSpecReportPath_inDoors)

Object o     = null
Link outLink = null
Baseline b   = null

for b in all m do
{
    // Load the current baseline and display it
    baselineM = load(m, b, true)

    for o in entire(m) do
    {
        for outLink in o -> "*" do
        {
            parentModName = target(outLink)
            iTarget= targetAbsNo(outLink)

            // Whatever else you want to do with each link
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, you would need to cycle through each baseline individually, then cycle through all of the objects in that baseline, then cycle through each link. I hope that answers your question!